# Generalized product-of-sums Boolean expression with n true variables out of m total variables

Tags: boolean, combinations, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

**Problem**

How do you write a "product-of-sums" Boolean expression, in *m* Boolean variables, which enforces at least *n* of those variables being 1/true?

**Attempt**

Starting in the "sum-of-products" form, my solution is as follows for the specific example of *n = 3* and *m = 4* (*A*, *B*, *C*, *D*):

```
(A and B and C) or (A and B and D) or (A and C and D) or (B and C and D)
```

The above expression is a mathematical combination (*without replacement*, order irrelevant) of every 3 variables out of the 4. In other words, it lists all the possibilities of 3 or more variables out of the 4 being logically high. As such, there are 4 *or*-separated (parenthesized) groups with 3 *and*-separated variables per group.

However, a software tool that I am using does not accept this format. I need to convert from the above expression's sum-of-products form of Boolean expression to the product-of-sums form, which is as follows:

```
(A or B) and (A or C) and (A or D) and (B or C) and (B or D) and (C or D)
```

Note that there are now 6 *and*-separated (parenthesized) groups with 2 *or*-separated variables per group. Though part of my attempted solution, I haven't been able to find a relationship between the number of groups and the number of variables per group between the sum-of-products form and the product-of-sums form. I would like to generalize the above solution for an arbitrary *n*, up to *n = 10*, and an arbitrary *m*, up to *m = 24*.

So, the problem may be re-phrased as follows: How do I convert from a sum-of-products expression, of all combinations of *n* out of *m* variables being logically high, to the corresponding product-of-sums expression? The solution ought to be generalized for an arbitrary (*n*, *m*) and not rely on CAS-type tools like [this](https://www.boolean-algebra.com/) which do not scale well to large problems. I am using Python and have looked at libraries like [pyeda](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), whose conversions to long product-of-sums expressions seem to be very computationally expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cardinality constraint

The Boolean `n-of-m` expression can be encoded as products-of-sums in several ways. A recommended paper is [Towards an Optimal CNF Encoding of
Boolean Cardinality Constraints](https://www.carstensinz.de/papers/CP-2005.pdf) of Carsten Sinz.

Basically, the encoding makes use of a combination of digital counter and digital comparator. The counter evaluates the number of variables equal to true. The comparator determines, if the resulting number ends up within the allowed range. The paper explains how to derive the [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF), the usual name for products-of-sums form.

### Converter tool [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/) to the rescue

In case you are not willing to implement such a solution yourself, you could resort to [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/). This is a small versatile tool, which is able (among other things) to convert `n-of-m` cardinality constraints to CNF in [DIMACS format](https://jix.github.io/varisat/manual/0.2.0/formats/dimacs.html).

Input for an `at-least-10-of-24` example:

```
BC1.0
//  at least 10 of 24
_x := [10,24](a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x);
ASSIGN _x;
```

The resulting CNF is generated in fractions of a second. It has 460 clauses.

Make sure to use the `-all` parameter. Otherwise, you'll just get a CNF to check for general satisfiability.

### CNF cardinality encoding in Python

A Python implementation of cardinality encodings is provided by [PySAT](https://pysathq.github.io/docs/html/api/card.html). [pysat.card](https://pysathq.github.io/docs/html/api/card.html) encodes cardinality constraints into a CNF formula.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers my question perfectly. I used bc2cnf to recreate your result with 460 clauses. I see that it has 159, not 24, variables -- are the extra variables auxiliary to make the computation more efficient and/or make the output more concise?

Comment: Yes. The additional variables are auxiliary or switching variables. Imagine a circuit of Boolean gates. The 24 primary inputs feed the circuit. But between primary inputs and circuit output is a path of auxialiary gates. Details can be found under Tseytin encoding or [Tseytin transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation).